# How to add error handling in angular 8 using snackbar without using centralized error handling

Tags: angular, error-handling, snackbar

I have this code in client.add.component.ts and want to do error handling for Duplicate entry. I get 503 error in console currently.

```
this.clientsSvc.createClient(client).subscribe(x => this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: this.route}));
```

How to add the following line to the above code?

```
this.snackBar.open(`Duplicate Client Name`, null, {duration: 3000});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to show/handle error only when the current request fails for `createClient`

In that case to check status code in the error callback.

```
this.clientsSvc.createClient(client)
.subscribe(
   x => this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: this.route}),
   error => {
     if(error.status === 503) {
       this.snackBar.open(`Duplicate Client Name`, null, {duration: 3000});
     }

   }
);
```

Comment: I have the following code in client.service.ts file.


 createClient(post: Partial<API.Client>) {
    return this.http.post(this.api_url, post).pipe(
      tap(_ => this._updateClients.next(null))
    );
  }

How to change this?

Comment: I think you always have the full response in the error callback, don't you ? I think the "observe" parameter only applies to the "success" callback...

Comment: @smiti you don't have to change the code in `client.service.ts` change `this.clientsSvc.createClient(client).subscribe(x => this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: this.route}));` with the code that I mention in the answer

Comment: @Random My bad. You're right, updated the answer. Thanks for headup :)